# Why OpenMP do-loop that actually generates parallel process, can NOT be detected by OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()?

Tags: fortran, openmp

I can not understand why !$OMP DO is actually distributing tasks to different threads but cannot be detected by using openMP intrinsic function OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM().

```
program test
implicit none

integer :: i,su
double precision a(10), b(10),c
INTEGER OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM

su=0


!$OMP DO
do i=1,10
   b(i) = 10*i;
   c = b(i);   
   write(*,*)'in the loop, rank =',c,OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
enddo
!$OMP END DO

!$OMP PARALLEL
write(*,*) 'Rank = ',OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
!$OMP END PARALLEL

end
```

The result is:

```
 in the loop, rank =   10.000000000000000                0
 in the loop, rank =   20.000000000000000                0
 in the loop, rank =   30.000000000000000                0
 in the loop, rank =   40.000000000000000                0
 in the loop, rank =   50.000000000000000                0
 in the loop, rank =   60.000000000000000                0
 in the loop, rank =   70.000000000000000                0
 in the loop, rank =   80.000000000000000                0
 in the loop, rank =   90.000000000000000                0
 in the loop, rank =   100.00000000000000                0
 Rank =            0
 Rank =            6
 Rank =            1
 Rank =            7
 Rank =            2
 Rank =            5
 Rank =            4
 Rank =            3
```

See? It seems that only Master thread can be seen by public in the DO-LOOP. It is unfair since it is not his only one contribution.

Comment: `!$OMP DO` -- looks like you forgot to instantiate a parallel region. Try `!$OMP PARALLEL DO`

Comment: Thanks! I got it! I was mislead by a F95 handbook on the website. It contains a lot of things I feel scattered.  So I think !$OMP PARALLEL DO is equal to first !$OMP PARALLEL then next line: !$OMP DO  . Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `do` loop is not in a parallel region, so it is not parallelized -- all loop indices *are* processed by thread 0.

If I change your program to include a parallel region

```
...
!$OMP PARALLEL
!$OMP DO
do i=1,10
   b(i) = 10*i;
   c = b(i);
   write(*,*)'in the loop, rank =',c,OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
enddo
!$OMP END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL
...
```

then I get proper output of OMP thread numbers:

```
 in the loop, rank =   50.000000000000000                8
 in the loop, rank =   20.000000000000000                3
 in the loop, rank =   20.000000000000000                7
 in the loop, rank =   20.000000000000000                4
 in the loop, rank =   20.000000000000000                5
 in the loop, rank =   20.000000000000000                9
 in the loop, rank =   20.000000000000000                6
 in the loop, rank =   20.000000000000000                0
 in the loop, rank =   20.000000000000000                1
 in the loop, rank =   30.000000000000000                2
```

This particular output also exposes a flaw in your code, namely that `c` is shared, so its value is being clobbered by each thread.  Also, if the `do` loop is the only thing in the parallel region you can combine the OMP directive.  Finally, if we change your code to:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO private(c)
do i=1,10
   b(i) = 10*i;
   c = b(i);
   write(*,*)'in the loop, rank =',c,OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
enddo
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

then the output will be correct.

```
 in the loop, rank =   100.00000000000000                9
 in the loop, rank =   30.000000000000000                2
 in the loop, rank =   20.000000000000000                1
 in the loop, rank =   70.000000000000000                6
 in the loop, rank =   60.000000000000000                5
 in the loop, rank =   50.000000000000000                4
 in the loop, rank =   80.000000000000000                7
 in the loop, rank =   90.000000000000000                8
 in the loop, rank =   10.000000000000000                0
 in the loop, rank =   40.000000000000000                3
```

Comment: @PabPeter if an answer was useful to you, you can show thanks by upvoting (with a little more rep) and if it solved your problem you can show thanks by accepting it (clicking the checkmark net to the answer).

Comment: Sorry casey, I cannot because of my reputation is lower than 15.

Comment: @PabPeter I know you cant upvote yet, but you can accept.